# Can I darken my grout?

Tags: grout

We have just tiled our bathroom and the grout is not as dark as I wanted it.  I love it when it is wet and is the color that I wanted it to be but lightens up when dry. Do you recommend getting the grout stain/paint? Or is there something else I could do.  Could I get it wet and before it dries put a sealer on it?

Comment: There are "wet-look" sealers, that after applying the sealer the grout should look like it does when wet, even when the grout is dry (plus it should not change color when wet).

Answer (score 2):

Grout stain is certainly the easiest option I have tried. The one I used came in a pen form and I just coloured in all the grout one afternoon when the bathroom was dry. I wouldn't try it with damp grout as the absorption might be unpredictable.