# Can I apply grout over grout to change the color?

Tags: tile, grout

We grouted tile on counter tops and glass tile backsplash last night and the grout looks white and it was supposed to be a tan color. Can I grout over it with a darker coloured grout?

Comment: Related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/24873/can-i-darken-my-grout

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, not without removing the grout that has already been applied, and that is a truly miserable exercise.

The link in the comment from Niall is your best bet.  Sealer/stain.